# what do these methods basically do in models.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am reading some codebase and I have this slight confusion in models.py.
Here is the code .

```
class Product(models.Model):
    DISCOUNT_RATE = 0.10

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    sale_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    sale_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, upload_to='products')

    def is_on_sale(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if self.sale_start:
            if self.sale_end:
                return self.sale_start <= now <= self.sale_end
            return self.sale_start <= now
        return False

    def get_rounded_price(self):
        return round(self.price, 2)

    def current_price(self):
        if self.is_on_sale():
            discounted_price = self.price * (1 - self.DISCOUNT_RATE)
            return round(discounted_price, 2)
        return self.get_rounded_price()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product object ({}) "{}">'.format(self.id, self.name)
```

My concern is that what do methods such as current_price do here ? Are they a fields in Product model. 
I am slightly unaware of creating models with methods .

Comment: No these are not fields, these are simple methods defined on a `Product`. The database is not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you call {{ current.price }} in the html, it does the math - discounted_price = self.price * (1 - self.DISCOUNT_RATE) - and then displays the answers. Essentially, it lets you run code outside the views.py ...